Union as minimal set under subset relation
I'm running myself in circles trying to lay out in detail the following (what should be trivial) proof in ZFC:
Let $\{A_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a set of sets.
Let $A$ be a set such that $\forall i : A_i \subseteq A$.
Then $\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \subseteq A$.
I've gotten myself to the fact that for the union:
$$\forall (x \in \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n): \exists A_i (x \in A_i)$$
while for $A$ this is not guaranteed.

Apologies if I'm wrong but $0$ is not a natural number, $A_{i}$ where $i=0$ is not included in the other statement where $n$ starts at $0$? So there's no $A_{0}$ in both statements?

depends but question is the same either way

(In fact, it seems reasonable to conjecture that most mathematicians believe $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ - link - but this is ultimately entirely tangential to the issue at hand.)

If $x \in \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n $ then by definition, $x \in A_n$ for some natural number $n$. Hence $x \in A$. Hence the result.

From the definition of a subset, $A_i\subseteq A\iff (\forall x(x\in A_i\implies x\in A))$, which means
$$\forall \left(x\in\bigcup^\infty_{n=0}A_n\right):\exists A_i(x\in A_i)\implies\forall\left(x\in\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n\right):x\in A,$$
which directly implies that $\bigcup^\infty_{n=0}A_n\subseteq A$.
